# Messy Code When Drawing Graph by R on linux

Tags: r, linux, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to draw graph by R on linux,
when I run this code: plot(1,1)
a graph with messy code is drawn

[image: graph]

I am using OS linux, R 3.4.1 , jupyter notebook
Cairo is used as device for drawing.
I have tried these methods:

1. trying another method in R
2. trying another font
3. trying utf-8 encode

but these are not work.
It should not be problem of jupyter notebook because I run R console and draw the graph, the same problem happened. It should be problems in R, or Cairo, or something between them.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by reinstalling R.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on a Linux machine where I used a `conda` installed R system running in Jupyter Notebooks. The issue for me turned out to be missing fonts. I solved it by using `conda` to install fonts:

`conda install -c anaconda fonts-anaconda`